# Is it a bad practice to pass "this" as parameter inside its own constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this `BdlTabItem` which receives a parameter of type `DockableUserControl` and would like to know if is it a bad practice to create a circular reference between the two by using `uc.TabItem = this` and `new BdlDockableWindow(this)` before the constructor finishes.

I know this behavior can be considered really bad with unmanaged native code (C++). So, even though I didn't have any warnings or errors, I ask here if I should do this or not.

```
public BdlTabItem(BdlTabControl parent, DockableUserControl uc, string title)
    {
        TabControlParent = parent;
        UserControl = uc;
        WindowParent = new BdlDockableWindow(this);

        this.Content = UserControl;

        UserControl.TabItem = this;
    }
```

Comment: See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away/ for a blog post I wrote on the topic rather a long time ago.

Comment: @Kilouco: in most practical cases there should be no issues with this approach.

Comment: "I know this behavior is not even possible with C++"... I continue to be amazed by the incorrect facts people "know".  Of course, in C++ there is a difference... the object under construction has dynamic type of the type whose constructor is running, not the eventual most-derived type.  But still, leaking `this` during C++ construction is quite possible.

Comment: Oh. My bad. Been years since I stopped programming in C++.
I'll edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is acceptable, but raises questions. Why is the tab item instantiating a new `WindowParent` but the parent tab control doesn't have a reference to it? Or why isn't the window parent a property on the user control being passed in? Seems like the behavior should be elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe using a factory pattern would do better here?
I really need everything connected so I can have references from anywhere on this logical tree.

Comment: @Kilouco having the references is fine, but having something that needs a reference also be in charge of the instantiation of the object is a bit suspect. It's just odd to have a tab item be instantiating a window. Might I recommend [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: You could make the parent window a property of the user control (if that is where it belongs--it seems like it does). Then just either reference the window internally using the user control, or in the constructor, set a property on the tabitem to the property on the user control. You don't necessarily need to have everything you need to access be directly passed in to a constructor, they can be properties on objects you pass in to the constructors as well.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a "BdlTabItem" that actually holds an "tabItem" and a Window because I want to be able to alternate it (transform the tabItem into a Window and vice-versa). That's why I've done it this way.

Comment: I'd recommend adding some context and calling code, and posting on Code Review. I think you'll get much more in-depth feedback there. Just make sure you provide enough code and context.